# Material ui pickers, how to prevent closing on redraw

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mobx-react

I have a picker which is a part of a component where the date is given from another, super, component.

If the super component is redrawn (say due to a date change) the component that holds the datepicker is destroyed and recreated, thus losing the "open" state.

How would I make this managed? - I can manually state if a picker is "open" or not. However I cannot seem to hook up to the "click on date bar" or "click outside calendar", thus I cannot actually *control* this.

The component containing the picker:

```
export class DateDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {date, onChange, onAccept, onOpen, label, openState} = this.props;

        return <>
            {label && <Typography variant={'subtitle2'} display={'inline'} style={{marginRight: '1ch'}}>
                {label}
            </Typography>}
            <DatePicker
                value={date}
                onOpen={() => {
                    this.setState({open: true},onOpen)
                }}
                onChange={onChange}
                onAccept={onAccept}
                format={'ddd, D MMMM YYYY'}
                variant={'inline'}
                open={openState}
                onClick={e => {
                    console.log('we clicked the picker')
                }}
            />
        </>
    }
}
```

And the super component which would be responsible for "managing" the datepicker:

```
export class DatesList extends React.Component {
    this.onSave = async () {/*code to request a save to the backend*/};
    onStartEditing = () {/*code to visually indicate we're editing a field*/};

    render() {
        const {dates} = this.props; //date is a moment + meta data.
        const sorted_dates = Array.from(eventData.dates.values()).sort(
            (l, r) =>
                (!l.start_date ? 0 : l.start_date.valueOf()) - (!r.start_date ? 0 : r.start_date.valueOf())
        );
        sorted_dates.map(date => {<div>
            <DateDisplay
                 label={'Event start date:'}
                 date={date.start_date}
                 onOpen={(e) => {
                     this.onStartEditing(e, 'start_date');
                 }}
                 onChange={(newDate) => {
                     date.start_date = !nullOrUndefined(newDate) ? newDate.toDate() : newDate;
                 }}
                 onAccept={async () => {
                     await this.onSave('start_date');
                 }}
            />
        </div>});
    }
}
```

As a side question: I notice that the components are not rebuild if the sorting is removed, even though there is a single element in the list thus sorting would always give the same "order", why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own state for opening/closing. 
Use `open` prop and `onClose` and `onOpen` callbacks. Deeper example from documentation: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/controlling-programmatically